# How to create new function in Ocean?

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am using Ocean 2010.2 and I cannot create a new function with CreateFunction method. It says, that "it does not exist in the current context".
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you added some code example on how you try to create your function. For now I can propose that your didn't add necessary Petrel assemblies to your project.

Here is my example of creating function:

```
Collection SimpColl = Collection.NullObject;
Function SimpFunction = Function.NullObject;
// Do not forget to use transactions
using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    // Use current project to create collection
    // that will contain your function
    trans.Lock(PetrelProject.PrimaryProject);
    SimpColl = PetrelProject.PrimaryProject.CreateCollection("Simple collection");
    trans.Commit();
}

using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction())
{
    // Create your function in your newly created collection
    trans.Lock(SimpColl);
    SimpFunction = SimpColl.CreateFunction("Simple Function");
    trans.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CreateFunction method can be called for the Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Analysis.AnalysisRoot, Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Seismic.InterpretationCollection and Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.Collection objects. 
Pattern is the same in all cases. But your message doesn't look as an Ocean error, but it looks as a generic VS message. The common reason for messages like this is usually if: the declaration of object and the usage of object are located in two different isolated blocks of code and not visible to each other.